# Binary operator '<^>' cannot be applied to operands of type

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11, argo

I has the follow code implemented to work with **Argo** framework, has been working until the **Xcode 11.2.1** update. when I updated my Xcode Version the follow error appears:

> Binary operator '<^>' cannot be applied to operands of type '(()) ->
>   VoiceMailNumberResponse' and 'Decoded<_?>'

Here's my code:

```
struct VoiceMailNumberResponse{
    var name: String?
    var value: String?
}

extension VoiceMailNumberResponse: Argo.Decodable {
    static func decode(_ json: JSON) -> Decoded<VoiceMailNumberResponse> {
        let voiceMailNumberResponse = curry(VoiceMailNumberResponse.init)
        return voiceMailNumberResponse
            <^> json <|?  "name"
            <*> json <|?  "value"
    }
}
```

Error appears on line: `"<^> json <|?  "name"`

In addition I'm using **Argo**, **Curry** and **Runes** for parsing JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: This answer is based only off your code sample and has not been tested.*

As both the properties of `VoiceMailNumberResponse` are optional then Xcode 10.1/Swift 4.2 (the version tested with) produces two `init` methods:

```
init()
init(name: String?, value: String?)
```

If neither, or just one, property is an optional only the second `init` is produced. From the question it appears Xcode 11.2.1/Swift 5.1 behaves the same way.

The type in the error message:

```
(()) -> VoiceMailNumberResponse
```

indicates that the compiler has selected the `init()` to pass to `curry`, while the code expects the `init(name: String?, value: String?)` to be passed.

As the code apparently worked with some previous Xcode/Swift this would appear to be a change in behaviour.

This could be a change to, or "feature" of, the language and/or compiler. You can probably work around it by explicitly specifying which `init` to use by including the parameter names, e.g. something like:

```
...
let voiceMailNumberResponse = curry(VoiceMailNumberResponse.init(name:value:))
...
```

That said it would be best to figure out if:

- this is a language/compiler change, and therefore **Argo**, **Curry** and **Runes** might need updating which you should report (the version history indicates there have been ambiguities addressed before);
- a "feature", in which case you should head over to feedbackassistant.apple.com and file a bug report; or
- something else

You might also want to look at using [Swift's `Decodable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable), introduced in Xcode 9, to decode the JSON as an alternative to using these third-party packages.

HTH

Comment: Instead of selecting `init` via intermediate variable and manual type declaration, you can also specify `init` in full form with all selectors: `curry(VoiceMailNumberResponse.init(name:value:))`

Comment: @user28434 – Good catch! Should have remembered that, I'll edit the answer.